# Shuffle string using Arrays

Tags: python

can someone please explain why my solution is wrong in this case?
Q : You are given a string s and an integer array indices of the same length. The string s will be shuffled such that the character at the ith position moves to indices[i] in the shuffled string.

Return the shuffled string.
Input: s = "codeleet", indices = [4,5,6,7,0,2,1,3]
Output: "leetcode"
Explanation: As shown, "codeleet" becomes "leetcode" after shuffling.

Sol:

```
class Solution:
    def restoreString(self, s, indices):
            res = [''] * len(s)
            for i in range (len(s)):
                res.insert(indices[i],s[i])
            return "".join (res)
```

[image]

Comment: You can see your code in action here: http://pythontutor.com. It should make the problem obvious. You don't want `insert`, you want `res[indices[i]] = s[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix it with this code

```
for index, alph in enumerate(s):
        res[indices[index]] = alph
```

```
def restoreString( s, indices):
    res = [''] * len(s)
    for index, alph in enumerate(s):
        res[indices[index]] = alph
    return "".join (res)
restoreString("codeleet",[4,5,6,7,0,2,1,3])
```

or dict option

```
    dicts = {}    
    res = ''
    
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        dicts[indices[i]] = s[i]          
    return ''.join(dicts.values())
```

Comment: `res` is pointless here, and a dict seems like a weird choice, which will in fact probably not work in somewhat older Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with insert, look at what it is doing over the iteration:

```py
class Solution:
    def restoreString(self, s, indices):
        res = [''] * len(s)
        for i in range (len(s)):
            res.insert(indices[i],s[i])
            print(res)
        return "".join (res)
```

out:

```
['', '', '', '', 'c', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']
['l', '', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']
['l', '', 'e', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']
['l', 'e', '', 'e', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']     
['l', 'e', '', 't', 'e', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']
```

As deceze mentioned in the comments, instead use `res[indices[i]] = s[i]`

```py
class Solution:
    def restoreString(self, s, indices):
        res = [''] * len(s)
        for i in range (len(s)):
            res[indices[i]] = s[i]
        return "".join (res)
```

out:

```
leetcode
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print `res` before doing `join`, we can see that it's equal to

```
['l', 'e', '', 't', 'e', '', '', '', 'c', 'o', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', '']
```

With insert, you are not replacing elements in your array, but you are adding new ones.

Instead you can do `res[indices[i]] = s[i]`

```
class Solution:
    def restoreString(self, s, indices):
        res = [''] * len(s)
        for i in range (len(s)):
            res[indices[i]] = s[i]
        return "".join (res)
```